# Outlet for short communication

Tags: references

I have written an 8-pages technical paper (more theoretical than applied) in statistics. I only know of two journals (Biometrika and Statistics and Probability Letters) that publish such short communications and I was wondering whether there are other journals that take this kind of articles.

Comment: What is the general statistical area? Plenty of recent *JASA* articles are in the 7-11 page range. As long as the contribution is strong, I wouldn't worry about the length so much. First and foremost, reputable journals want to publish good contributions that advance the field.

Comment: @cardinal Thank you for your comment. The topic is on mathematical statistics but the results are not of the JASA type IMO. In my case, I think I need a medium journal (I know that if the results are strong enough, even AOS would take it but, unfortunately, this may not be the case of my manuscript).

Comment: Related: [Recommendation for peer-reviewed open-source journal?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/28117/2970)

Answer (score 1):

A possible outlet for this is the recently created journal Stat:

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)2049-1573

The Editorial Board is good and they seem to provide quick peer-reviews.

For the econometrics minded audience, another good Open-Access option is [The Econometrics Journal](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/1368423x). The review times are fast and there is a 20pg limit.